# how to customize autocompletetextview in android

Tags: android, autocomplete, customization

I am working with android2.2.

I want to customize Autocompletetextview in android.
I used following link for customization http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/custom-autocomplete-for-android.html

[image]

this is my customize autocompletetextview control.and I am write multiple text & when i press # at that time it will go for filter.

**#aaaa# and #abaa# both text selected from list.** and **I want to become this to word as link or display bold.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [this](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/08/easy-method-for-formatting-android.html)  link and as per ur [link](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/custom-autocomplete-for-android.html) **do changes in repeatText function**

like

```
@Override
    protected void replaceText(final CharSequence text) {
        String textData = previous + text + getSeperator();     
        super.replaceText(setSpanBetweenTokens(textData, "#", new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC)));
}
```

You will get filtered text as bold

Comment: thanks @pavan.. I also got one more link like use html.. http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-adding-styling-to-a-text-bold-italic-etc/